# How can i change filename in console automatically

Tags: ubuntu, replace, find

I have a great number of files whose name is "img800400_497708.307247.png" and i would like to change in console all the points by an underscore. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=*.png
for file in $files; do
file="${file:0:-4}"
[[ "$file" == *"."* ]] && newfile="${file//./_}" && mv "$file.png" "$newfile.png"
done
```

save it and then run it. Be sure to be in the directory where the files are in, when running it.